# Database for HTML5 offline application

Tags: jquery, json, html, offline-caching

How to use a `JSON` string(pretty large) as a database for `HTML5`

I know we can use `localStorage.setItem('key',value)` for storing a specific value.Im having a `JSON` string that contains 200 to 300 records

```
[{"key":"value"....},
{"key":"value"....},
{"key":"value"....},
......
.....
...
//around 300
]
```

Right now im putting this entire `JSON` in a `div` with `display` said to `none` and accessing that `JSON` like this

```
$.parseJSON($('#mydivid').html());
```

Any other alternate suggestion ? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use directly the localStorage with localStorage['key'] ? Why use a div ?

Comment: @dystroy Please see my requirement..im having a big JSON

Comment: Where is it coming from ? And why the div ?

Comment: Actually its a entire database encoded using php 's `json_encode` function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Supposing you have a json file (many MB if you like) generated by your server, you can fetch it with a simple ajax query, parse it, and then use it as

```
var myval = database['somekey'];
```

You shouldn't wrap it in your html, it prevents the normal caching of your page if only the database changes.

Your json would be stored or generated in a second separate .json file (that you can very well generate in PHP).

The function to fetch it would look like this :

```
var database;

function fetchDatabse(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                database = eval('('+httpRequest.responseText+')');
                if (callback) callback();
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'database.json?time='+(new Date().getTime()));
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
```

Note that it's usually better to fetch only parts of a database using ajax queries.

---

If you **really** want to embbed your json in your page, instead of embedding it in a hidden div, embedd it in a script :

```
<script>
var database = {
   ...
};
</script>
```

Comment: Where do i store the json for accessing it..?

Comment: Here's an exemple : http://dystroy.org/re7210/ the html page queries the recipes database which is defined in a json file.

Comment: let me check..thanks..this works like a charm i know..but things are different when the app becomes offline..i cant find the external json

Comment: You want your webapp to be available offline ? Have a look at [this](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/) if you **really** think this is an important requirement.